# Automatically add extension when saving in R

Tags: r

I am using the tcltk package in R to create a GUI, and I am trying to write a function in R that automatically adds a .xlsx extension to the end of a file name when saving.  However, when it calls the Save As window, it doesn't add the extension.  Any help is appreciated, thank you.

```
library(openxlsx)
library(tcltk)
saveFile1 <- function(){
  write.xlsx(c, tclvalue(tkgetSaveFile(
    filetypes = "{ {Excel} {*.xlsx} }")))
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, Matt Jewett!  Thank you, this answered my query perfectly!

Comment: The specific thing I was looking for was the defaultextension = ".xlsx" line.  That adds the .xlsx automatically to the end of the file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do the trick.

```
saveFile1 <- function(c){
  require(tcltk)
  require(openxlsx)

  # Prompt for file
  filepath <- tclvalue(tkgetSaveFile(filetypes = "{ {Excel} {*.xlsx} }", defaultextension = ".xlsx"))

  # Check if file was specified
  if(filepath != ""){
    # Ensure that the last 5 characters are .xlsx
    filepath <- ifelse(substr(filepath, nchar(filepath) - 4, nchar(filepath)) == ".xlsx", filepath, paste0(filepath,".xlsx"))

    # Write the file
    write.xlsx(c, filepath)
  }
}

# Test the function
saveFile1(mtcars)
```

Comment: If you are curious about some other parameters you can plug into tkgetSaveFile, you can see them listed here https://wiki.tcl.tk/1060

Comment: The tools package has some functions that are handy for this sort of thing: `file_ext`, `file_path_sans_ext`